# Python macOS os module: Can't find path

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, operating-system, openpyxl

when running my python script for saving a .xlsx document on the local computer and trying to open the same file after with the system() function from the python os module, i catch this specific error on screen:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51hmD.png)

(Translated to English: Path not found)

The code used for saving the file is wb.save() from openpyxl workbook:

```
wb.save(saved_file := (f"{path}Skiftplan ({name} - {shift}).xlsx"))
```

where:

```
{path} = /skiftplaner/November/
{name} = "onsdag"
{shift} = "17:00 - 20:00"
```

And the code for opening the file is:

```
system(f"open -a '/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app' '{realpath(saved_file)}'")
```

Now the weird thing about this is, that if i replace any character in `name = "onsdag"`, the program works and the path can be found. ex: `name = "0nsdag"` will work, or `name = "onsdaj"`, but i would like the variable name to be "onsdag".

And i have prior to the shown code checked if the path exists, and if not then created it, which does work, but the system() function can't find the file if the {name} = "onsdag"

I've tried changing the {name} variable to ex. "0nsdag", "onsdaj" and other values, which have worked.

The file does get created by the wb.save() function, but can't be found by the system() function

Comment: The file path/name in the error message doesn't match what's in your code, and the filename part, "`Skiftplan (onsdag - AFTEN - 17:00 - 20:Skiftplan (onsdag - AFTEN - 17:00 - 20:00).xlsx`", looks like it got double-expanded somehow (like the "`00).xlsx`" at the end got replaced by another copy of the entire filename). I'd check what `saved_file` and `realpath(saved_file)` are at that point in the code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but i've tried this and when i print both the saved_file and realpath(saved_file), i don't get the same path as it tries to find in the system() function, it gives the right path and the same path output in both saved_file and realpath(saved_file) print statements: /Users/andersballeby/Desktop/McDonalds Programmer/Main Project/McDonalds-Leader-Panel/skiftplaner/November/onsdag d. 30-11/Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx

Comment: Is there an alias file or symbolic link or something at that location?

Comment: What do you mean by symbolic link? - Otherwise, there is an excel file at the location that saved_file is assigned to, and it can also find the file by the realpath() function, but the weird thing is the system() function changing the path whilst executing. I thought it could be something to do with bash and tried to echo the location, which gave me the same result as printing the saved_file location - which is the right path. It doesn't make sense why it's the right path when doing "echo" instead of "open" in bash

Comment: What happens if you run `open -a '/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app' '/Users/andersballeby/Desktop/McDonalds Programmer/Main Project/McDonalds-Leader-Panel/skiftplaner/November/onsdag d. 30-11/Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx'` in a regular interactive shell? Also, does `ls '/Users/andersballeby/Desktop/McDonalds Programmer/Main Project/McDonalds-Leader-Panel/skiftplaner/November/onsdag d. 30-11/Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx'` show the file has any interesting properties?

Comment: Okay this is very bizarre, the program suddenly works and im not quite sure what i did to fix it, but i'll answer my own question with the steps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Spaces in filenames are usually escaped. In such cases, it's best to use os.path or pathlib to build tha path name rather than using strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following the steps from @Gordon Davisson:

I tried pasting `open -a '/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app' '/Users/andersballeby/Desktop/McDonalds Programmer/Main Project/McDonalds-Leader-Panel/skiftplaner/November/onsdag d. 30-11/Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx'` into my terminal, which returned the same error message as on the image at the top of this thread.

Then i tried pasting the other command: `ls '/Users/andersballeby/Desktop/McDonalds Programmer/Main Project/McDonalds-Leader-Panel/skiftplaner/November/onsdag d. 30-11/Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx'` which just returned the same file with no interesting properties at all.

Then by removing the file and simply just looking at the `ls November/onsdag d.30-11/` folder, i saw this:

```
Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx
Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:~$00).xlsx
```

This got me to look in my finder directory folder, and I could only see the first file, not the second file.

After this i tried closing all instances of excel and somehow it just works now, if i try doing `ls November/onsdag d.30-11/` again, it only returns the single file im looking for:

```
Skiftplan (onsdag - MID - 12:00 - 17:00).xlsx
```

This now went on to fully function in the program, and it's now able to open the excel file without any errors or complications whatsoever.